# Why was my rsync filter question regarding a business merger closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

i asked [rsync not removing single quotes around array of strings --filter list](https://serverfault.com/questions/505802/rsync-not-removing-single-quotes-around-array-of-strings-filter-list)  on ServerFault, but it was closed as off-topic without explanation.

i am trying to automate a safe way to move files from multiple machines that came to our business with an acquisition.  i specifically mention safe because i know these machines are heavily infected with malware and cannot have them boot up on our HIPAA protected LAN.  i posted the question to ServerFault because that is the site where i found the most relevant existing answers to my questions.  A very similar question about mutt on ServerFault is referenced, but that is not closed.

Maybe a better solution would be to tag the question with SuperUser, StackOverflow or some other means so that i can continue to do my JOB until at such time that it definitively belongs on another site.

I do not know any sysadmins who consider simple bash scripting software development.

Comment: Other bash and rsync questions on SF.    http://serverfault.com/questions/239256/error-in-bash-rsync-script?rq=1

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/505047/multiple-spaces-in-folders-and-files-for-rsync-backup-via-bin-bash-bin-sh/505052?noredirect=1#505052

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/420374/problems-with-bash-variable-expanding-with-single-quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't vote to close this question, but I came pretty close. I thought about it for a while.

I'll take a wild guess at why some people voted to close it:

The business context you mentioned in your question *here* is utterly missing from your question on the main site. Thus, it might have looked like an academic exercise. Such academic questions often get closed as off-topic or migrated to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), one of the sites where enthusiast questions often get better answers.

If I were you, I would be sure to add the overall context to the question, so that it's easier to see that it's a professional question. This not only discourages people from marking your question as off-topic, but also lets people come up with alternate approaches which may help with your overall issue.

Comment: i believe adding context to the question would just make it longer and less likely to be read, not to mention demonstrate lack-of-focus.  Thank you for the suggestion.  i already know many alternate ways to solve this, but since i am a professional, i need to know why this is not working.  If i had not tested this, i would have polluted our existing network with malware.  Professional IT people need dependable, repeatable, and robust automation.  Alternate ways to solve a problem are sometimes a way of skirting around the issue.

Comment: The point is, it wasn't at all clear from your question that you _are_ a professional. You may need to make that clear.

Comment: i understand Michael and appreciate your candidness and insight of the SE platform.

Comment: No problem. [sf] is different than other Stack Exchange sites in that we reject questions which aren't in a professional context. Some people get a bit carried away with it, though, since we have a very large number of such questions.

Answer (score 4):

The smart-mass answer is that 5 people with 3k+ rep thought it should be closed.

The mod answer: I have no idea what they were thinking and have re-opened it.

I see no reason it should be closed. As I have no insight into their close reason I can only make vague assumptions as to why they voted the way they did. The question could be a bit more clear...

Comment: The abruptness and lack of transparency have turned me off StackExchange too many times.   Thank you for being blunt.

Comment: @rjt - I'll pipe up. I voted to close (and migrate to Unix.SE, I believe) for the reasons Michael Hampton brought up in his answer. There was no clear indication your question was in a professional context. I know and thank your for not cluttering your question with unnecessary background but sometimes a little background is the difference between solving the problem the right way and solving the problem the *wrong* way.

Comment: @kce, thank you for letting me know. I was not aware there was a vote to migrate.